# question about saddle-node bifurcation in a $2$D-system of vector fields

Tags: bifurcation, nonlinear-dynamics

> Consider a two dimensional continuously differentiable vector fields
>   in $\mathbb{R}^2$ $$\dot{u}=a(1-u)-uv^2$$ $$\dot{v}=uv^2-(a+k)v$$ where
>   $a,k>0$ are parameters. Show that saddle-node bifurcation occurs at
>   $\displaystyle k=-a\pm \frac{\sqrt{a}}{2}$.

A saddle-node bifurcation is defined at a point if two equilibrium points annihilate each other upon changing the parameter values $a,k$. The given system has two stable equilibrium points $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ since their Jacobian is $\begin{pmatrix} -a & 0 \\ 0 & -(a+k) \end{pmatrix}$. Now we need to vary the parameters $a,k$ in such a way that these two equilibrium points annihilate each other. But how to do this in $2$-dimensional system I don't understand. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equilibrium points are at

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & u & v \\
 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 2 & \frac{a+\sqrt{a \left(-4 a^2-8 k a+a-4 k^2\right)}}{2 a} & \frac{a-\sqrt{a \left(a-4 (a+k)^2\right)}}{2 (a+k)} \\
 3 & \frac{a-\sqrt{a \left(-4 a^2-8 k a+a-4 k^2\right)}}{2 a} & \frac{a+\sqrt{a \left(a-4 (a+k)^2\right)}}{2 (a+k)} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

The equilibrium points $\{2,3\}$ collapse (have the same coordinates) at $k = -a \pm\frac{\sqrt{a}}{2}$: thus for $k = -a+\frac{\sqrt{a}}{2}$ they collapse in $\{\frac 12,\sqrt{a} \}$ and for $k = -a-\frac{\sqrt{a}}{2}$ in $\{\frac 12,-\sqrt{a} \}$